# Apache Camel: asyncCallback reply threads change in Camel 17 and Camel 18/19

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-camel

With Camel version up to 17.x all calls on the `Synchronization.onComplete()` callback over `activemq:queue` were done in different threads and so even if the processing of the response inside the *onComplete* was very slow the messages did not got blocked and queued. This should be the result of the `asyncConsumer=true&defaultTaskExecutorType=ThreadPool&concurrentConsumers=2&maxConcurrentConsumers=100` configuration as I understand.
So an example output for this showcase is :

```
Received async reply: 2000 OK
Received async reply: 3000 OK
Received async reply: 5000 OK
Received async reply: 9000 OK
Received async reply: 10000 OK
Finished async reply: 2000 OK
Finished async reply: 3000 OK
Finished async reply: 5000 OK
Finished async reply: 9000 OK
Finished async reply: 10000 OK
```

So "finished" logs are after all "received" as each is called in a different thread. All replies are received async and how long one is handled doesn't affect receiving of the others.

After upgrading to Camel 18.x (or 19.x) this is no longer the same. And now receiving a reply and handling (long process) it blocks receiving of the others. This is because the same thread(s) is used to call the *Synchroniztion.onComplete()* an thus replies are queued until fully handled.

```
Received async reply: 2000 OK
Received async reply: 10000 OK
Received async reply: 9000 OK
Finished async reply: 2000 OK
Received async reply: 3000 OK
Finished async reply: 3000 OK
Finished async reply: 9000 OK
Finished async reply: 10000 OK
Received async reply: 5000 OK
Finished async reply: 5000 OK
```

I thought that these new properties configure exactly this: *replyToConcurrentConsumers=2&replyToMaxConcurrentConsumers=100* and that if a new message comes it would be processed and replied in a new thread if all current threads are processing right now (and of course if max count is not reached then it's normal a thread to process several messages and queue them)

Maybe I do something wrong but how to configure the route so to get I could get similar result as in Camel 17. Increasing the *replyToConcurrentConsumers* property it works but I think it should be scaled dynamically and rely on *replyToMaxConcurrentConsumers* if needed.

The code :

```
public class AsyncCallbackTest {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncCallbackTest.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create and setup a default Camel context
    final CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    setupRoutes(camelContext);
    camelContext.start();

    // real test
    asyncCallbackTest(camelContext);

    camelContext.stop();
    System.exit(0);
}

private static void setupRoutes(CamelContext camelContext) throws Exception {
    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("activemq://queue:asyncTest?asyncConsumer=true&defaultTaskExecutorType=ThreadPool" +
                    "&concurrentConsumers=2&maxConcurrentConsumers=100")
                    .process(exchange -> {
                        final String msg = String.valueOf(exchange.getIn().getBody());
                        exchange.getOut().setBody(msg + " OK");
                    });
        }
    });
}

private static void asyncCallbackTest(CamelContext camelContext) throws Exception {
    final int[] delays = new int[]{9000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 3000};

    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(delays.length);

    final Synchronization callback = new SynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Exchange exchange) {
            LOG.info("Received async reply: " + exchange.getOut().getBody());
            final int delay = (int) exchange.getIn().getBody();
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    this.wait(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            LOG.info("Finished async reply: " + exchange.getOut().getBody());

            super.onComplete(exchange);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(Exchange exchange) {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    };

    final ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();

    for (int i = 0; i < delays.length; i++) {
        final Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(camelContext);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(delays[i]);
        exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);

        producerTemplate.asyncCallback("activemq://queue:asyncTest?" +
                        "replyToConcurrentConsumers=2&replyToMaxConcurrentConsumers=100",
                exchange, callback);
    }

    countDownLatch.await();
    camelContext.stop();

}
```

}